# How to make an API request with selectableDayPredicate of flutter datePicker

Tags: flutter

I want to set a selectable date using the selectableDayPredicate parameter in flutter's showDatePicker.
I'd like to use the API to determine the selectable date, but if I use http in the function to be passed, the return value is Future, so I'm having a problem because I can't pass the response result well.

```
showDatePicker(context: context, selectableDayPredicate: _checkDate);

bool _checkDate (DateTime date) {
    bool? result;
    http.get("https://***/" + DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date))
        .then((response) {
            result = response.body;
        });
    // result is null because http.get() is asynchronous
    // When I try to async/await, the return value of _checkDate becomes Future, so I can't pass it to selectableDayPredicate which expects bool.
    return result!;
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this problem? Or did you find the suitable pub of datepicker to achieve this goal? I have the same issue and now searching for the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to refer below code :

```
Future _checkDate () async {
 final response =
  await http.get(Uri.parse("https://***/" + DateFormat("yyyy-MM- dd").format(date)));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

  return json.decode(response.body);
  } else {

    throw Exception('Failed to load date');
  }
}
```

Comment: if return value is Future, this error occurred.

```
The argument type 'Future<bool> Function(DateTime)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool Function(DateTime)?'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use await instead of then, Await will wait for the result but then will not wait for result.

```
 final result = await http.get("https://***/" + DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date))
 return result;
```

Comment: If I use async / await, the return value must be Future. And when I use Future, this error occurred.
```
The argument type 'Future<bool> Function(DateTime)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool Function(DateTime)?'
```

Comment: You cannot make API calls there, Its better to get all the valid dates through API before showing the datePicker

Comment: so that's how it is.
It is difficult to get the status of all days in advance because the API response will be very slow.
Find a way with another datePicker.
thank you for the advice.